# MYSQL query data and combine, group and order results

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am having trouble getting a query to work effectively which only queries 1 table. Here is an example of the table data:

```
ID    NAME     PARENT_ID    SORT_ORDER
1     Home     NULL         1
2     Contact  NULL         3
3     Service  NULL         2
4     Service1 3            0
5     Service3 3            2
6     Service2 3            1
```

What I would like to do is to return the data from this table with results that have a PARENT_ID appearing under the result with that ID, and to have all results then display in their SORT_ORDER. Here is how I would like the query to result the above data:

```
ID   NAME     PARENT_ID    SORT_ORDER
1    Home     NULL         1
3    Service  NULL         2
4    Service1 3            0
6    Service2 3            1
5    Service3 3            2
2    Contact  Null         3
```

Any feedback to make this happen is very welcome.

Kind regards,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your logic correctly, you could use this:

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  yourtable t1 LEFT JOIN yourtable t2
  ON t1.PARENT_ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(t2.SORT_ORDER, t1.SORT_ORDER),
  t1.PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL,
  SORT_ORDER
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bcd8/1).